# How to remove all zeros from a number using the function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to write a removeZeros function that takes an integer n and returns a new number consisting of all digits n except zeros. Only zero always remains zero.

Examples:

removeZeros (100) === 1

removeZeros (-2410) === -241

removeZeros (102) === 12

removeZeros (0) === 0

Comment: Does 102 == 12?

Comment: Solution:https://codepen.io/nexo12/pen/jOZoJpo

Answer (score 0):

```js
const removeZero = (n) => {
    if (n === 0) return 0;
    return String(n).replaceAll('0', '')
}

console.log(removeZero(100))
console.log(removeZero(0))
console.log(removeZero(-2410))
```

Comment: Your function returns string when number is != 0. So as author wanted: removeZeros (100) === 1 would be false

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
const removeZeros = (number) => {
  if (typeof number !== 'number' || number === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  const numberWithoutZeros = number.toString().replaceAll('0', '');

  return Number(numberWithoutZeros);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of 0 at the end of your number you can divide it by 10 until the last digit is not 0 or the number is 0 so you don't fall into infinite loop.

```js
function removeZeros(n){
  while(n%10 === 0 && n!=0){
    n = Math.floor(n/10);
  }
  return n;
}
console.log(removeZeros(100));
console.log(removeZeros(1001));
console.log(removeZeros(-200));
console.log(removeZeros(-200200));
```

If you however want to remove all zeros you can convert the number into string and replace all "0" with "". After that you can convert it back to number:

```js
function removeZeros(n){
  return Number(String(n).replaceAll("0",""));
}
console.log(removeZeros(100));
console.log(removeZeros(1001));
console.log(removeZeros(-200));
console.log(removeZeros(-200200));
```

Answer (score 0):

First cast the number to a string and then replace all trailing zeroes. Finally, check if the new string is a valid number and parse it, or return zero.

```js
/**
 * Removes all trailing zeroes for a given number.
 *
 * @param {number|any} n - a number with trailing zeroes
 * @return {number} number with all trailing zeroes removed
 */
const removeZeros = (n) =>
  (m => m !== '' && !isNaN(m) ? parseInt(m) : 0)
  (`${n}`.replace(/0*$/, ''));

console.log(removeZeros(  100) ===    1)
console.log(removeZeros(-2410) === -241)
console.log(removeZeros(    0) ===    0)
console.log(removeZeros(  102) ===  102) // legal?
```

If you want to remove all the zeroes then you can simplify this to:

```js
/**
 * Removes all zeroes for a given number.
 *
 * @param {number|any} n - a number with zeroes
 * @return {number} number with all zeroes removed
 */
const removeZeros = (n) =>
  (m => m !== '' && !isNaN(m) ? parseInt(m) : 0)
  (`${n}`.replace(/0/g, ''));

console.log(removeZeros(  100) ===    1)
console.log(removeZeros(-2410) === -241)
console.log(removeZeros(    0) ===    0)
console.log(removeZeros(  102) ===   12) // legal?
```

Comment: There appears to be duplicate targets for "removing trailing 0s", but not one for "remove all 0s" (at least not one that I could find). I'd like to edit the question to just focus on the latter, but I don't want to invalidate your answer. Would you be willing to update the answer to include a solution for that? If so, I'll go ahead and edit the question.